# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode_plus'

Tags: python, nlp, attributeerror, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to use XLNet model for my sentiment classification project but I am receiving this error.

```
from transformers import XLNetTokenizer, XLNetModel
PRE_TRAINED_MODEL_NAME = 'xlnet-base-cased'
tokenizer = XLNetTokenizer.from_pretrained(PRE_TRAINED_MODEL_NAME)



input_txt = "India is my country. All Indians are my brothers and sisters"
encodings = tokenizer.encode_plus(input_txt, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=16, return_tensors='pt', return_token_type_ids=False, return_attention_mask=True, pad_to_max_length=False)
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-4b204650a45a> in <module>()
      1 input_txt = "India is my country. All Indians are my brothers and sisters"
----> 2 encodings = tokenizer.encode_plus(input_txt, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=16, return_tensors='pt', return_token_type_ids=False, return_attention_mask=True, pad_to_max_length=False)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode_plus'
SEARCH STACK OVERFLOW
```

Why is my tokenizer recognized as NoneType?

Comment: This error tells you quite clearly that `tokenizer` is `None`.  That means that `XLNetTokenizer.from_pretrained` is returning `None`.  So, check for that, then try to figure out why it's returning `None`.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue with my XLNet - it turns out that the order that you import/ install XLNet and SentencePiece makes a difference.

In this case, you should import SentencePiece before the transformers package. This will allow python to better understand the relationship between tokenizer and SentencePiece.

So your code should look something like this:

```
!pip install sentencepiece transformers

import sentencepiece
from transformers import XLNetTokenizer, XLNetModel


PRE_TRAINED_MODEL_NAME = 'xlnet-base-cased'
tokenizer = XLNetTokenizer.from_pretrained(PRE_TRAINED_MODEL_NAME)

input_txt = "India is my country. All Indians are my brothers and sisters"
encodings = tokenizer.encode_plus(input_txt, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=16, return_tensors='pt', return_token_type_ids=False, return_attention_mask=True, pad_to_max_length=False)
```